# running unit test cases with sentence_transformers causes all-distilroberta-v1 not found

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry, sentence-transformers

we have python project in following structure

```
dataanalysis
├── config
│  └── config.env
├── coverage.xml
├── Dockerfile
├── poetry.lock
├── pylibs
│  └── analyzer-1.0.0.tar.gz
├── pylint-report.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── result.xml
├── scripts
│  ├── __init__.py
│  ├── common.py
│  ├── analyze_data.py
│  ├── analyze_main.py
│  └── analyze_scheduler.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    │  ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │  ├── conftest.cpython-38-pytest-7.4.0.pyc
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test_analyze_data.py
    ├── test_env_vars.py
    └── test_analyze_main.py
```

we bundle this as docker image and able to run python scripts. for we install all required libraries using pip as follows

```
cp ./scripts  /home/app_user/scripts
cp ./pylibs  /home/app_user/pylibs
cp requirements.txt /home/app_user
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt
pip install --no-cache-dir /home/app_user/pylibs/analyzer-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

we are trying to run unit test cases for this we use poetry to create virtual env and run test cases in it.

```
#pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "dataanalysis"
version = "1.0.0"
....

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pycron = "3.0.0"
swifter = "1.3.4"
Levenshtein = "0.20.9"
numpy = "1.22.0"
pandas = "1.1.5"
scikit-learn = "0.24.1"
scipy = "1.5.3"
sklearn = "0.0"
mysql-connector-python = "8.0.32"
analyzer = {path = "pylibs/analyzer-1.0.0.tar.gz"}
textdistance = "^4.5.0"
sentence_transformers="^2.2.2" # added this explicitly as unit test fails specifying this is module not found. (which not case in production)

[tool.poetry.group.test.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.3"
pytest-coverage = "^0.0"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

and run our test cases as `poetry run pytest`

our test cases fails with message `sentence_transformers module was found`.
so added sentence_transformers dependency in pyproject.toml.
now we get following error

```
***ValueError: Path /Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/dataanalysis-uwOjF3tf-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/analyzer/files/all-distilroberta-v1 not found

../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/dataanalysis-uwOjF3tf-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py:77: ValueError***
```

this all-distilroberta-v1 is found in virtual environment that was created manually but not in environment created by poetry.

sentence_transformer module is used inside python script under `analyzer-1.0.0.tar.gz`

can you please help to resolve this.